# Check out the commit referenced by tag?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML file in a repository as follows:

[image]

As you can see here, it's checking out another repository repoxyz. During build/release, it always picks up the latest commit from `develop` in repoxyz. Is it possible to specify a commit instead of picking up the latest commit?

I found this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref)

> - checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@refs/tags/MyTag # checks out the commit referenced by MyTag.

But not sure how to do that.

Comment: Does it work when you set `ref` (which is currently `develop`) to `MyTag`?

Comment: @user989988 Have you started by looking at the "tags" section of a Git tutorial? Tags are a well-documented feature in Git where a quick Google search will yield thousands of helpful results. There's no need to wait on someone to look it up for you and post a link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line #5 of your screenshot:

```
ref: developer
```

Change it to:

```
ref: refs/tags/MyTag
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean I don't want to specify branch name in ref? Is the tag specific to a branch?

Comment: No, tags are NOT specific to a branch.  Tags point to a commit, and that commit can be on any branch.  For example, your main branch is tagged at commit 100, then you create a new feature branch (feature1) to do some work.  Your feature branch will also have that tag.  This is fine because you have all the work of the main branch and just adding on.  In Git everything can be a pointer, and a tag is just a pointer.